# General process to verify limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I am not new to calculus but I never really understood how to verify limits using the epsilon-delta definition. Is there  a general process to do it? If there is one, please explain it as I have not been able to find one on the internet. The limits I found as examples were always easy to verify ( e.g. $\lim\limits_{x\to3}{2x-6=0}$ ). But how do you verify, for example, $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}{e^{\frac {1}{x}}}=1$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Several ways: continuity, making a substitution (try $x\mapsto 1/z$; where's the new limit?), squeeze theorem...what are you familiar with?

Comment: Using the continuity of the exponential function, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac1x\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\right).$$  Is this second limit something you can prove?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}{e^{\frac {1}{x}}}=\lim\limits_{v\to 0}{e^v}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for limits where the variable approaches some finite real number, say
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ you must show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$ where $L$ denotes the value of the limit. You seem familiar with this from your post.

In the case of limits where the variable approaches infinity, you must show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M \in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x > M$, $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. So in your example, you must verify that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x > M$, you have $$|e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1|< \varepsilon.$$